# Google Programmable Search Engine: Search only for HTTPS websites

Tags: search-engine, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api, code-search-engine

I want to configure my google search engine in order to search only for HTTPS websites. I found something like Google Programmable Search Engine. I am now struggling to configure the HTTPS-pattern of the websites to search (see the screenshots below).
[image]

[image]

https://www.*:443 also doesn't work.
Maybe there is another way to achieve my goal (without the google programmable search engine)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about setting up a Google custom search engine and not about a programming problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller But the Google custom search engine ist a custom JavaScript-Widget that you can embed into your own website/webapp. So thats programming relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `inurl` Google Search Operator is what was I looking for.
Lets say I want search with the keywords "buy bitcoin" a https secured website I can type now in the google search field:

buy bitcoin inurl:https://

A negative example will include not https protected marktplaces:
buy bitcoin inurl:http://